# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 439 (Application inactive)

Tags: javascript, c#, console

I was developping a web application in Visual studio 2015 and I seem to get this javascript error in my browser console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 439
>   (Application inactive)

I googled this error which me normally helps me to understand them but i'm afraid it's not helping this time. Could you guys help me understand this error?

Specs:

- Building webapplication
- C#
- MVC5
- The error doesn't seem to stop my application
- The error can be found in the console view of my developper tools in chrome.
- The error is an javascript error

If you guys have some suggestions, or need more information: please feel free to ask.

**tl;dr what does this thing means:** 
*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of(Application inactive)*

**Steps to the solution**
Okay so now thanks to BugFinder I know that this applies: http://blog.nactive.be/2016/09/application-insights-http-status-code-439/ I'm going to check this out and post more if I know more :)

Comment: Does http://blog.nactive.be/2016/09/application-insights-http-status-code-439/ apply?

Comment: @BugFinder do you perhaps now the steps he takes in the blog?

Comment: No,  he contacted ms.  Because looking at it something wasnt set up or wasnt paid for

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: What do you mean you "seem" to get this error?  Do you get the error or not?

Answer (score 8):

I came here because an application of mine started getting HTTP Status Code 439 from Application Insights, apparently because I'm accidentally spewing diagnostics at them, and my app has been put in a time-out by them until tomorrow.

So, while poking around, I got Bing's cached version of the blog post above. Essentially, they were in a situation where they 1) sent a lot of diagnostics to Application Insights, and 2) had no one log on to AI to actually look at it, so Application Insights just turned them off. At least we now know what 439 is: a custom HTTP status code created by the Application Insights team to indicate a specific account error. The post was:

## Application Insights HTTP Status code 439 (Application Inactive)

In the application I currently work on application insights (AI) is implemented a year ago. We don’t really use it so much, it logs all the data for when we need it but we don’t check it every week.

Today in production we noticed that our AI calls to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track received a HTTP status code 439 (Application Inactive) with as response body:

```
{  
   "itemsReceived":2,
   "itemsAccepted":0,
   "errors":[  
      {  
         "index":0,
         "statusCode":439,
         "message":"Application inactive"
      },
      {  
         "index":1,
         "statusCode":439,
         "message":"Application inactive"
      }
   ]
}
```

If you google for it you don’t really find any thing useful (hence this post).

After a while I remembered why our application was inactive. I will post the mail we received from Microsoft and I suppose it says enough. After doing what they say everything worked again as expected.

[image: Explanation from Application Insights team]

I know this was a stupid error that should never had happened. In a normal situations you would have read the mail from Microsoft (and checked AI), you would use application insights a lot more any way. But in reality you only have so many hours in a day and there are always more important thing to do. And then you spend an hour solving a problem that should never have been there in the first place...

Comment: Just ran into this as well.  Apparently it can happen even when using localhost??? Have to look into how to disable it for localhost, but jeez what a hidden gotcha.  Unsure as to why they can't just shut off the logging on their end rather than hosing up your entire application - potentially in a production environment just for not manually viewing the logs...

Comment: @jelleB  I think this should be marked the answer.